# How to know if iframe is blocked?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Some website don't allow you to view their website in an iframe. I would like to know what code I could use to identify this and redirect to another page in this situation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11129279/1169519 . Though the post is few years old now, things might have been changed. Anyway, some sites are redirecting to `about:blank`, [that you can detect](http://jsfiddle.net/h2fk312h/), since you can access to its properties. If the buster redirects to a simple page which tells you can't show it in an iframe, I'm afraid there's not much you can do.